# HTML/JS Select onchange isn't working for some select items

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to HTML and JS and a bit stumped at the moment trying to get a select tag to fire off onchange. From reading through SO questions, I know of two ways to do it. One being the `onchange="script"` field in the select tag. The other is via referencing the element ID in `window.onload` and calling `selectItem.onchange`.

Strangely neither is working for me on the `'firstSelect'` select element in the following code even though they do work for the select tags above it. In fact I can't seem to reference any element ID below the `tr` that contains the `'hitter'` select element; even if I copy the hitter row and simply change the id and name, it doesn't work. The ejs does seem to work just fine for all the selects.

For the firstSelect element, I have tried the `window.onload` (script in the head) and using  `onchange="firstSelected"` in the select tag. Neither seem to have any effect.

I am sure that I've done some silly beginner thing or overlooked something, but would appreciate any help.

(For brevity in the post, I removed a bunch of link .css and script bootstrap tags, that I can add back if it's relevant.)

------**index.ejs**------

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <title>Blort!</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
           var firstSel = document.getElementById("firstSelect");

            firstSel.onchange = function() {
                onFirstSelected(firstSel.value);
                document.getElementById('hitSpd').innerHTML = Blort;

            }
        };
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Incredibly Stylish Result Calculator</h2>
    <form>
      <div id="defense">
        <h3>Defense</h3>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <th>Player</th>
                    <th>Hand</th>
                    <th>MOV</th>
                    <th>COM</th>
                    <th>VEL</th>
                    <th>AWR</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for="pitcher">Pitcher:&nbsp;</label>
                        <select id="pitcher" name="pitcher" onchange="onPitcherSelected(this.value)">
                            <% var selected; 
                            var nameTeamPos; 
                            print.forEach(function (player) { 
                    if (typeof pitcherObj != 'undefined'){
                      selected = player.id == pitcherObj.id ? "selected" : "";
                    } else {
                      selected = "";
                    }
                                nameTeamPos = player.PlayerStatsName + "  - " + player.Team + " - " + player.PPos + ((player.SPos.length == 0) ? "" : ("|" + player.SPos))%>
                                <option value="<%= player.id%>" <%= selected%>><%= nameTeamPos%></option>
                            <% }) %>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td id="pitHand"><%=pitcherObj.Hand%> </td>
              <td id="pitMov"><%=pitcherObj.Movement%> </td>
              <td id="pitCom"><%=pitcherObj.Command%> </td>
              <td id="pitVel"><%=pitcherObj.Velocity%> </td>
              <td id="pitAwr"><%=pitcherObj.Awareness%> </td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="catcher">Catcher:&nbsp;</label>
                <select id="catcher" name="catcher" onchange="onCatcherSelected(this.value)">
                  <% var selected; 
                  var nameTeamPos; 
                  print.forEach(function (player) { 
                    if (typeof catcherObj != 'undefined'){
                      selected = player.id == catcherObj.id ? "selected" : "";
                    } else {
                      selected = "";
                    }
                    nameTeamPos = player.PlayerStatsName + "  - " + player.Team + " - " + player.PPos + ((player.SPos.length == 0) ? "" : ("|" + player.SPos))%>
                    <option value="<%= player.id%>" <%= selected%>><%= nameTeamPos%></option>
                  <% }) %>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td id="catHand"><%=catcherObj.Hand%> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td>EYE: </td>
              <td id="catEye"><%=catcherObj.Eye%> </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td>DEF: </td>
              <td id="defAvg"><%= Math.floor((parseInt(pitcherObj.Awareness) + parseInt(catcherObj.Eye)) / 2);%> </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
      </div>

      <div id="offense">
        <h3>Offense</h3>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <th>Player</th>
            <th>Hand</th>
            <th>CNT</th>
            <th>EYE</th>
            <th>POW</th>
            <th>SPD</th>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="hitter">Hitter:&nbsp;</label>
                <select id="hitter" name="hitter" onchange="onHitterSelected(this.value)">
                  <% var selected; 
                  var nameTeamPos; 
                  print.forEach(function (player) { 
                    if (typeof hitterObj != 'undefined'){
                      selected = player.id == hitterObj.id ? "selected" : "";
                    } else {
                      selected = "";
                    }
                    nameTeamPos = player.PlayerStatsName + "  - " + player.Team + " - " + player.PPos + ((player.SPos.length == 0) ? "" : ("|" + player.SPos))%>
                    <option value="<%= player.id%>" <%= selected%>><%= nameTeamPos%></option>
                  <% }) %>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td id="hitHand"><%=hitterObj.Hand%> </td>
              <td id="hitCnt"><%=hitterObj.Contact%> </td>
              <td id="hitEye"><%=hitterObj.Eye%> </td>
              <td id="hitPow"><%=hitterObj.Power%> </td>
              <td id="hitSpd"><%=hitterObj.Speed%> </td>
            </tr>
<!-- No HTML Elements below here seem to work properly. -->
            <tr>
              <td>
                <label for="firstSelect">First:&nbsp;</label>
                <select id="firstSelect" name="firstSelect" >
                  <% var selected; 
                  var nameTeamPos; 
                  runnersList.forEach(function (player) { 
                    if (typeof firstObj != 'undefined'){
                      selected = player.id == firstObj.id ? "selected" : "";
                    } else {
                      selected = "";
                    }
                    if (player.id == 0){
                      nameTeamPos = player.PlayerStatsName;
                    } else {
                      nameTeamPos = player.PlayerStatsName + "  - " + player.Team + " - " + player.PPos + ((player.SPos.length == 0) ? "" : ("|" + player.SPos))
                    }
                    %>
                    <option value="<%= player.id%>" <%= selected%>><%= nameTeamPos%></option>
                  <% }) %>
                </select>
              </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td> </td>
              <td id="firstSpd"><%=firstObj.Speed%> </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div> 

        <button>Go!</button>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var list = <%- JSON.stringify(print) %>;
      var runnersList = <%- JSON.stringify(runnersList) %>;

      var pitcher;
      var catcher;
      var hitter;
      var first;
      // var second;
      // var third;

      function onPitcherSelected(id) {
        setPlayers();
        setPitcherAttributes(pitcher);
        setDefensiveValue();
      }

      function setPitcherAttributes(player){
        document.getElementById('pitHand').innerHTML = player.Hand;
        document.getElementById('pitMov').innerHTML = player.Movement;
        document.getElementById('pitCom').innerHTML = player.Command;
        document.getElementById('pitVel').innerHTML = player.Velocity;
        document.getElementById('pitAwr').innerHTML = player.Awareness;
      }

      function onCatcherSelected(id) {
        setPlayers();
        document.getElementById('catHand').innerHTML = catcher.Hand;
        document.getElementById('catEye').innerHTML = catcher.Eye;
        setDefensiveValue();
      }

      function onHitterSelected(id) {
        setPlayers();
        setHitterAttributes(hitter);
      }

      function setHitterAttributes(player){
        document.getElementById('hitHand').innerHTML = player.Hand;
        document.getElementById('hitCnt').innerHTML = player.Contact;
        document.getElementById('hitEye').innerHTML = player.Eye;
        document.getElementById('hitPow').innerHTML = player.Power;
        document.getElementById('hitSpd').innerHTML = player.Speed;

        // document.getElementById('hitAwr').innerHTML = player.Speed;

      }

      function onFirstSelected(id) {
        // setPlayers();
        document.getElementById('firstSpd').innerHTML = Changed;
        // setTotalSpeedValue();
      }

      function setPlayers(){
        pitcherId = document.getElementById('pitcher').value;
        catcherId = document.getElementById('catcher').value;
        hitterId = document.getElementById('hitter').value;
        // firstId = document.getElementById('first').value;
        // secondId = document.getElementById('second').value;
        // thirdId = document.getElementById('third').value;

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
          if (list[i].id == pitcherId){
            pitcher = list[i];
          }

          if (list[i].id == catcherId){
            catcher = list[i];
          }

          if (list[i].id == hitterId){
            hitter = list[i];
          }
        }

        // for (var i = 0; i < runnersList.length; i++){
          // if (runnersList[i].id == firstId){
          //   first = runnersList[i];
          // }

        //   if (runnersList[i].id == secondId){
        //     second = runnersList[i];
        //   }

        //   if (runnersList[i].id == thirdId){
        //     third = runnersList[i];
        //   }
        // }
      }

      function setDefensiveValue(){
        var value = Math.floor((pitcher.Awareness + catcher.Eye)/2);
        document.getElementById('defAvg').innerHTML = value;
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit:** fixed typo pointed out.

Comment: First of all where do you have `firstBlort` id? I don't see it in the DOM

Comment: That was a typo that should be corrected. firstBlort is really firstSelect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are `Blort` and `Changed` variables, or did you intend to assign a string to innerHTML? In reference to:

```
document.getElementById('hitSpd').innerHTML = Blort;

...

document.getElementById('firstSpd').innerHTML = Changed;
```

Try changing it to:

```
document.getElementById('hitSpd').innerHTML = 'Blort';

...

document.getElementById('firstSpd').innerHTML = 'Changed';
```

Otherwise you will be causing an [`Uncaught ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. That's exactly what it was. I must have been confused between the string in the JS versus being able to enter text directly in the HTML tags.